# How to bind multiple classes with ternary conditions?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Assume `labelCls, mandatory` and `optional` are predefined CSS classes.

Sample Code:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":labelCls (isRequired == "required"?mandatory:optional")}}>
  Warning!
</div>
```

Wanted to be if `isRequired = "required";`

```
<div class="labelCls mandatory">
  Warning!
</div>
```

Comment: OK, and what are you getting instead? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xopofa/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: That logic should be happening in your controller instead...

Comment: Suppose if i'm extending Ember.Component and writing that logic in a function, How to call that function in template?? Give me sample syntax please? :)

Answer (score 1):

Install [ember-truth-helper](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) addon for eq helper

```
<div class={{if (eq isRequired 'required') 'labelCls mandatory' 'labelCls optional'}}>
      Warning!
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be reactive.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you want to do this inside a component. So...

You can have a component that's defined as follows:

```
App.ReqClassComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  isRequired: function(){
    var someParam = this.get('someParam');
    return someParam === 'required';
  }.property()
});
```

Then, you can call the component in your template as follows:

```
{{ req-class someParam='required' }}
```

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xopofa/2/edit?html,js,output)